# How to programmatically list Installed video codecs?

Tags: c#, list, video, codec

Do you know how to programmatically obtain a list of video codecs installed on computer, from windows forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms are UI elements, so they won't help you there.

As far as retrieving video codec lists, at a high level:

1. Use [DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539/best-way-to-enumerate-all-available-video-codecs-on-windows)
2. You can read from various registry keys that contain codec information
3. You can check file locations of the codecs you are looking for
4. You can attempt to open a video file internally and catch an exception where the codecs do not exist. This will likely require some custom code or an API

Also, for future reference, generally stating "I need code" will not net you favorable responses.